# bash paste: loop through pairs of files based on wildcard, generate separate output files

Tags: bash, loops, wildcard, paste, variable-expansion

I am trying to get the paste command to loop through pairs of files, pasting them together and outputing each as a unique file.
I've tried a lot of things, here are a few:

```
 for i in *_temp4.csv; do paste *_temp4.csv *_temp44.csv > ${i}_out.csv; done
 #Each output contains each input file (rather than pairs). Obviously this is because of the * wildcard
```

---

```
 for i in *_temp2.csv_temp4.csv; do paste $_temp2_temp4.csv $_temp3_temp44.csv > ${i}_out.csv; done
```

no error, empty output files

```
 for i in *_temp2.csv_temp4.csv; do paste ${_temp2_temp4.csv} ${_temp3_temp44.csv} > ${i}_out.csv; done
```

output:

```
 combo15.awk: line 12: ${_temp2_temp4.csv}: bad substitution
```

I think I must be missing something very basic about how $ gets used, but I've been googling all night to no avail.

my entire code, for context, although I don't see why the previous lines should influence anything about this.

```
 for i in *.dat; do awk 'NR > 23 { print }' ${i} > ${i}_temp1.csv; done

 for i in *_temp1.csv; do awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2==0{$2="between"}BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2==1{$2="lego"}BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2==2{$2="pin"}BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2==3{$2="dice"}BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2==4{$2="jack"}BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2==8{$2="escape"}{print}'  ${i} > ${i}_temp2.csv; done

 for i in *_temp2.csv; do awk -v OFS="," '{$4 = $1 - prev1; prev1 = $1; print;}' ${i} > ${i}_temp3.csv; done  

 for i in *_temp2.csv; do awk -F "," 'BEGIN{print "new line"}{print $2}' ${i} > ${i}_temp4.csv; done

 for i in *_temp3.csv; do awk -F "," '{print $5}' ${i} > ${i}_temp44.csv; done

 for i in *_temp2.csv_temp4.csv; do paste $_temp2_temp4.csv    $_temp3_temp44.csv > ${i}_out.csv; done
```

Comment: For the input files?

     trial_02_mid.dat
     trial_02_bottom.dat
     trial_03_top.dat


All the other outputs are generated as expected, only the last line is giving me trouble.

Comment: Yes, and the variations on it in my OP.

Comment: I am not sure, i understood your requirement. But is this what you need? `for i in *_temp4.csv; do paste "$i" "${i/_temp4.csv/_temp44.csv}" > ${i}_out.csv; done`

Comment: Almost!
`for i in *_temp4.csv; do paste "$i" "${i/_temp4.csv}" "${i/_temp44.csv}" > ${i}_out.csv; done`

almost works, but it has extra columns (each extra column is from *_temp4.csv file.

The question says .dat because those are the original input files, the temp files I am trying to paste together are named .csv
I am trying to use  the variable (which I think is coming from the wildcard at the beginning of the line) and append it with `_temp2.csv_tem4.csv` and `temp3.csv_temp44.csv` such that it takes the unique filenames created from the previous lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that names of your files grow uncontrollably. This change should solve this problem:

```
for i in *.dat; do awk 'NR > 23 { print }' ${i} > ${i}_temp1.csv; done

for i in *.dat; do awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2==0{$2="between"}BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2==1{$2="lego"}BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2==2{$2="pin"}BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2==3{$2="dice"}BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2==4{$2="jack"}BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2==8{$2="escape"}{print}'  ${i}_temp1.csv > ${i}_temp2.csv; done

for i in *.dat; do awk -v OFS="," '{$4 = $1 - prev1; prev1 = $1; print;}' ${i}_temp2.csv > ${i}_temp3.csv; done

for i in *.dat; do awk -F "," 'BEGIN{print "new line"}{print $2}' ${i}_temp2.csv > ${i}_temp4.csv; done

for i in *.dat; do awk -F "," '{print $5}' ${i}_temp3.csv > ${i}_temp44.csv; done

for i in *.dat; do paste ${i}_temp4.csv    ${i}_temp44.csv > ${i}_out.csv; done
```

Comment: Yes! That works perfectly!  I was going to worry about the crazy filenames later, but that fixed it. Thank you!